# Report Name required to be changed in Sales Order Entry Screen

Tags: acumatica

The Sales Order Report is required to be changed in the Sales Order Entry Screen- Reports -> Print Sales Order to a customized Sales Order Printed report ! Sitemap changes can do in the Report Menu ! Where is the code to change in the Entry Screen > Print Sales Order !

Comment: Are you trying to change the report number the Print Sales Order calls? Otherwise i would assume simply customizing the existing sales order report would work without having to change the number.

Comment: Yes I want to change report number ! Wish to keep the existing number as a backup report but by default the new report should come up !

Comment: if you are not using the original and simply trying to change the number for "backup" i would just re-use the original report number. All reports can be rolled back to the original. so they are all backed up.

Comment: I want to have flexibility of adding more reports in the Reports Action Bar. as well !

Comment: I saw the following link which explains how to do customization . http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2017/08/adding-new-report-button-on-invoices.html#more